# Модальное представление is deprecated

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Использую конструкции:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```

Мне пишут, что:

```
dismissModalViewControllerAnimated и presentModalViewController is 
deprecated:first deprecated in ios 6.0
```

Как исправить и что оно значит?

Comment: @ReNoi77, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
> (iOS 6.0)
> Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver.
>
> Deprecation Statement
> Use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead.

В переводе на русский: "Метод dismissModalViewControllerAnimated устарел (в понятии Apple, скорее всего, умрет версий через 3, но может и остаться). В общем, использовать его не рекомендуется. А также в комменте рекомендуется пользоваться методом `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` вместо `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: тоже самое с presentViewController:animated:completion: